# Graph the integrand and use geometry to evaluate the integral

Tags: integration

Graph the integrand and use geometry to evaluate the integral.

$$\int_{-3}^{3}|x|+8\,dx$$

Comment: Do you know how to graph $|x|$?

Comment: Isn't this a homework problem?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$3(11 + 8)/2$ area in the positive quadrant. Multiply by two for symmetry.

Comment: The question concerns the need to graph and use geometry to evaluate the integral. I don't see how your answer is at all helpful in that vein.

Comment: Graph has been added to the answer          .

Answer (score 1):

$|x| + 8$ is a "v"-shaped graph, opening upwards, with its vertex at (0,8) and the sides of the "v" having slope 1 and -1. To evaluate the integral geometrically just draw the quadrilaterals formed by $(-3,11),(0,8),(0,0),(-3,0)$ and $(0,0),(0,8),(3,11),(3,0)$ and use conventional area formulas for rectangle and triangle to find the area bounded by the graph and the x-axis.
[image]